# Prepend zeros to a value in PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
val1   val2  val3
271   70    151
213   1     379
213   3     90
213   6     288
20    55    165
```

I want to transform this data frame as:

```
val1   val2  val3
271   70    0151
213   01    0379
213   03    0090
213   06    0288
020   55    0165
```

How can I do that in pyspark? And is it possible to do it with Spark SQL? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 14):

For numeric types you can use `format_string`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import format_string

(sc.parallelize([(271, ), (20, ), (3, )])
    .toDF(["val"])
    .select(format_string("%03d", "val"))
    .show())
```

```
+------------------------+
|format_string(%03d, val)|
+------------------------+
|                     271|
|                     020|
|                     003|
+------------------------+
```

For strings `lpad`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lpad

(sc.parallelize([("271", ), ("20", ), ("3", )])
    .toDF(["val"])
    .select(lpad("val", 3, "0"))
    .show())
```

```
+---------------+
|lpad(val, 3, 0)|
+---------------+
|            271|
|            020|
|            003|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, format_string

df = spark.createDataFrame([('123',),('1234',)],['number',])

df = df.withColumn('number_padded', format_string("%012d", col('number').cast('int')))

df.show()
```

| number | number_padded |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 000000000123 |
| 1234 | 000000001234 |

Comment: It would be great if you could add commentary to help us understand your code